# Jinja Template whitespace issue

Tags: python-3.x, templates, jinja2

I am using xml Jinja template to create dynamic xml file.
so when using loops in jinja template as below

```
   <tag1>
       <tag2 name="NAME1">
           {% if required.data.present -%}
           <tag3 data = required.data.present.value />
           {% endif -%}
       </tag2>
   </tag1>
```

Iam expecting output to be :

```
    <tag1>
        <tag2 name="NAME1">
            <tag3 data = required_data />
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
```

but original output is:

```
    <tag1>
        <tag2 name="NAME1">
            <tag3 data = required_data />
            </tag2>
    </tag1>
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the minus sign you put on the `endif` is removing the spaces, and new lines, to the **right**: `{% endif -%}`.

You can have a proper ident removing the spaces to le **left** `{%- endif %}`:

```xml
<tag1>
  <tag2 name="NAME1">
    {% if required.data.present -%}
    <tag3 data = required.data.present.value />      
    {%- endif %}
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Displays:

```xml
<tag1>
  <tag2 name="NAME1">
    <tag3 data = required_data />      
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Comment: yeah . I tried as you suggested.</tag2> is getting printed in the same line of <tag3> with instead of aligning in the next line of <tag3>

Comment: It does only if you add a minus at **both** side of the endif: `{%- endif -%}`, what you want is exactly what is in the answer: `{%- endif %}`